# How to make a timer repeat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a timer like this in the system of lives:

```
public int lives;
public int maxLives;
public Image[] Live;
public Sprite FullHearts;
public Sprite EmptyHearts;

public float TimeLeft;
public bool TimerOn = true;
public Text timerText;

void Update()
{
        if (TimerOn)
            {
                if (TimeLeft > 0)
                {
                    TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
                    UpdateTimeText(TimeLeft);
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeLeft = 0;
                    TimerOn = false;
                    setLives();
                }
    }
}

void UpdateTimeText(float currentTimer)
{
    currentTimer += 1;

    float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(currentTimer / 60);
    float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(currentTimer % 60);

    timerText.text = string.Format("{0:00} : {1:00}", minutes, seconds);
}


public void setLives()
{

        if (lives < maxLives)
        {
           lives++;
            Debug.Log("Life: " + lives);
        }


        if (lives > maxLives)
        {
            lives = maxLives;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Live.Length; i++)
        {

        if (i < Mathf.RoundToInt(lives))
            {
            Live[i].sprite = FullHearts;
            }
        else
            {
                Live[i].sprite = EmptyHearts;
            }

            if (i < maxLives)
            {
              Live[i].enabled = true;
            }
        else
            {
                Live[i].enabled = false;
            }
        }
}

public void TakeHit(int damage)
{
    TimerOn = true;

    lives -= damage;

    if (lives < 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Game over");
        lives = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Live.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < Mathf.RoundToInt(lives))
        {
            Live[i].sprite = FullHearts;
        }
        else
        {
            Live[i].sprite = EmptyHearts;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason, one life is added. I tried to do it like this, but then all the lives are added at once.

```
  public void setLives()
  {
        if (lives < maxLives)
        {
           lives++;
           TimerOn = true;
           Debug.Log("Life: " + lives);
        }
   ....
       
}
```

And I need to add one life at a time when the timer expires, and turn on the timer until all the hearts are filled. I also tried through the cycle, but for some reason all the hearts were added again. Please tell me how it can be implemented?

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags. Just pressing one letter and `Enter` will often select the wrong tag. Like the C language tag instead of C#.

Comment: understood, thanks corrected)

Comment: `TimeLeft` is never reset.

Comment: @синго, I wrote in the update method, this: if (TimeLeft > 0)
                {...}
                else
                {  TimeLeft = 0;} or do you mean something else?

Comment: @синго, thank you, I understood what the reason was, it was necessary to put values for this variable

Answer (score 0):

You set `TimeLeft = 0;` if `TimeLeft <= 0` and in next frame of the game check `if(TimeLeft > 0)` agane, so system never go to branch change timer. So all action happen in very short time.

Comment: Thank you, I have already solved this problem)